# Joomla 4 Email Single User

Tags: joomla-4.x, user, emails

Is it possible to email an individual user from within the Joomla 4 admin area?

Preferably without using a paid plugin.

Comment: YOURSITE.com/administrator/index.php?option=com_messages&view=message

Answer (score 0):

@James has given the answer in his comment.

But just to elaborate, on the administrator menu go to

Users / Messaging / Private Messages